# mysql query to select distinct rows from table when values in a column starts with same string in php

Tags: mysql

i want to get the distinct rows from MySQL table , with the table having a column with values having same starting string

mysql,php,apache

```
SELECT DISTINCT advt_id FROM `advtspacebkg`
```

in table `advtspacebkg` column  `advt_id`  contains values like

```
'KNR28629/1','KNR28629/2','KNR28629/3',.....
```

how can i get the rows having `advt_id` starting with `'KNR28629'`

->thanks in advance

Comment: column contains comma separated values or single-single values?if single then use `LIKE` :- `SELECT DISTINCT advt_id
FROM advtspacebkg
WHERE advt_id LIKE 'KNR28629%';`

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) because of the comments you are making on the answers, the answer are good and should not give trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solve your problem.

*Query*

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(`advt_id`,LOCATE('/',`advt_id`) - 1)  FROM `advtspacebkg`
```

*Input*

```
advt_id
__________
KNR28629/1
KNR28629/2
KNR28629/3
KNR28630/1
KNR28630/2
KNR28630/3
```

*Output*

```
advt_id
________
KNR28629
KNR28630
```

Comment: Also got answer when using like        "SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(advt_id,'/',1) AS advtnumber FROM advtspacebkg
"

Answer (score 2):

Use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT advt_id
FROM advtspacebkg
WHERE advt_id LIKE 'KNR28629%';
```

Your query could also benefit from the following index on `advt_id`:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON advtspacebkg (advt_id);
```

Comment: *"thanks for your reply, But cant solve this "* Not sure what your problem is or what you are trying.. As this answer should give the results as expected assuming the question was the complete user case.. if not see mine comment your question..